# How to use paths instead of GET variables in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I had asked this before but the question was closed for the wrong reason.

Essentially, I have folders containing a PHP file `{dynamic}/blog/index.php`.

How can I make it so that someone can access `example.com/folders/{dynamic}/blog/unique` as if it were an actual HTML/PHP file?

Essentially, `unique` is a unique GET variable called `id`, which is representing `example.com/folders/{dynamic}/blog?id=unique`.

The `{dynamic}` can be anything, as there are hundreds of different folders under `folders` so I cannot create a separate rule for each one.

I am using NGINX, so cannot edit `.htaccess` files - how can I do this with NGINX?

ALso, this must work for all files except for a few.

There are certain IDs (about 5) that should point to their real filename, not the dynamic GET variable.

For example, `example.com/folders/{dynamic}/blog/example` represents an actual real file called `example.php` in that directory

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) together with a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router). That makes it easy to create URLs like your examples.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't want to use frameworks, but this is completely possible in NGINX + PHP. I just don't know how, and all the answers are written for Apache. The ones in NGINX aren't for dynamic folders and don't exclude certain files

Comment: I haven't said anything about any frameworks. The front controller pattern is a _pattern_ explaining a structure/flow and a router is just a library (which you can write yourself if you want to reinvent the wheel). This is how most semi modern to modern applications do it. In short: The web server passes all requests to non existing files on the server to index.php. There the router checks the URL and sees if any URLs added to the router is a match. If it is, it executes the callback you have configured it to execute on that match.

Comment: "closed for the wrong reasons" ? Not as all as far as I can see. _Exactly_ the right suggestion of a duplicate has been made. To me it appears as if you _still_ did not understand that a request does not have to target a physical file on the server side. And that not all responses are generated by a separate PHP or html file.

Comment: If you yourself understood that you cannot use a ".htaccess" file since you are using `nginx` - then _why_ do you tag this question with the tag ".htaccess"? That does not help...

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: @arkascha For your first comment, isn't that the point of StackOverflow? Why would I ask a question that I already know the answer to. Questions are asked because people may have gaps in their knowledge.

Comment: @arkascha That resource does not help. If someone is having an issue with NodeJS for example, that's like just commenting https://nodejs.org/en/docs/

Comment: Yes, the idea of answering questions is to help people. _But_ to keep this site working it is a requirement that you do your own research prior to asking and that you demonstrate your effort to solve the issue yourself. THat does not change just because you _claim_ that the first one had been closed "for the wrong reason".

Comment: And no, that reference I gave is _not_ a general reference to the basic documentation, but to the specific part where rewriting in nginx is explained. Which is what your question is about.

Comment: So please stop making excuses. Get to work. Work through the information you are offered, start out yourself. Then, when you have an own implementation which does not work as expected and where you fail to understand _why_ it does not work, _then_ is the time to ask here and then you are required to include your effort so far and a precise description what exactly does not work as you would expect. Those are the rules here. Sorry.

Comment: `Sorry` - no worries, apology accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below rewrite rule to configure as per your expectation

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/folders/(.*)/blog/example$ /folders/$1/blog/example.php last;
    rewrite ^/folders/(.*)/blog/(.*)$ /folders/$1/blog/index.php?id=$2;
}
```

Note: Like example.php, For other certain IDs (about 5) which you expect to point to their real filename, you can write the rewrite rules as per your needs.

The above configuration will resolve as below. I tested this in my local

```
Request Url  : http://localhost/folders/a/blog/hello
Resolved Url : http://localhost/folders/a/blog/index.php?id=hello

Request Url  : http://localhost/folders/b/blog/hello
Resolved Url : http://localhost/folders/b/blog/index.php?id=hello

Request Url  : http://localhost/folders/a/blog/example
Resolved Url : http://localhost/folders/a/blog/example.php

Request Url  : http://localhost/folders/b/blog/example
Resolved Url : http://localhost/folders/b/blog/example.php
```